# Possible to insert between each cell of a range in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am attempting to concatenate a list of objects with a line break into a single cell using this formula:

=CONCAT(A1,CHAR(10),A2,CHAR(10), etc.)

The problem lies in the fact that I have some of these concatenations that are 1,000+ rows long. Is there a way to select the entire range and then insert the ,CHAR(10), between each cell occurrence? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See answer for Excel 2016 or later. There is a way to do it in earlier versions but that includes some manual steps which you might want to avoid. Best bet is a very simple UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2016 or later, you can use `TEXTJOIN`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,A1:A1000)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. I had no idea you could use that to add a delimiter.